# How would i add a drop down menu to my jquery table which uses mysql?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

So currently I am trying to figure out how I would add a dropdown menu to the code I've posted below. I've searched the internet but could not find a way that worked for me, I'm very new to coding so this is kind of difficult for me others may find this easy.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead> <!-- add class="thead-inverse" for a dark header -->
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>USERNAME</th>
        <th>Crime(s)</th>
        <th>Active</th>
        <th>EDIT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
    </tr>
        </div>
      </th>
  </tfoot>';
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
  {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>  
                     <td class="username" data-id1="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["name"].'</td>  
                     <td class="crime" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["crime"].'</td>  
                     <td class="activated" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>'.$row["activated"].'</td>  
                     <td><button type="button" name="delete_btn" data-id3="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete">DELETE</button></td>  
                </tr>  
           ';
      }
      $output .= '  
         <tr>  
              <td></td>  
              <td id="name" contenteditable></td>  
              <td id="crime" contenteditable></td> 
              <td id="activated" contenteditable></td>  
              <td><button type="button" name="btn_add" id="btn_add" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">ADD ACCOUNT</button></td>  
           </tr>  
      ';
   }
   else
   {
      $output .= '<tr>  
                          <td colspan="4">Data not Found</td>  
                  </tr>';
   }
   $output .= '</table>  
      </div>';
   echo $output;
 ?>
```

Comment: To make it clear, i am wanting to add a dropdown when you click on the boxes under active that will have a few options and once clicked a dropdown appears and you select an option which then changes and updates.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/fqt7q2

Comment: Where are you trying to add the dropdown to? And what values should it contain @bluqe-bluqe

Comment: @AceKYD I am trying to add the dropdown to the activated section. And it would contain Yes, No, and Being Verified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you'd like to add the dropdown to the activated section of your table and that it should contain `Yes`, `No` and `Being Verified`, you can update that table column to be

```
<td class="activated" data-id2="'.$row["id"].'" contenteditable>
        <select name="activated" id="activated">
            <option value="Yes" '.(($row["activated"] == "Yes") ? 'selected="selected"':"").'>Yes</option>
            <option value="No" '.(($row["activated"] == "No") ? 'selected="selected"':"").'>No</option>
            <option value="Being Verified" '.(($row["activated"] == "Being Verified") ? 'selected="selected"':"").'>Being Verified</option>
        </select>
    </td>
```

This would allow the value from the db `$row["activated"]` get automatically selected in the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Just im struggling with css styling the button?

Comment: @BluqeBluqe glad it worked for you, don't forget to mark it as the answer. You can add a class to the `<select>` and then add your css for the dropdown. Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: Glad to help @BluqeBluqe, a good way to say thanks is to mark it as the answer :)